# Keep login across systems

Tags: php, authentication

I have this idea to unify 10 systems, they will all share the same user which will only login to the principal site, after that he will be able to log to any separated system without having to login again. What's the best way to accomplish this?

I'm using php and mysql on all my systems.

they are all running on the same domain, same server. They use different databases for each.

Comment: How are they connected/seperated?

Comment: they are not connected in any way, they all separated systems right now.

Comment: Are they running in the same domain? Using a common database? Please provide all the details available in order to provide a proper solution.

Comment: i've updated my question to provide those details. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, without full details its hard to say. I've done this and its actually not so difficult. The trick is to have all of your users in a common database, or to create a common piece of code that all websites use for user validation that will individually scan all user databases.

If your apps are sub-domains of a single domain, have a look at [these docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain)

`ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");`

Comment: i was thinking about a webservice maybe... yet i'm not really shure abut using a service for that. Maybe a cookie on the browser?

Comment: If your apps are all on the same domain, there is no reason not use standard login procedures (using $_SESSION, etc..). A web service is not needed at all for this type of thing. if you put all of your login procedures in a single file (lets call it `loginprocedures.php`) then all you have to do is include `loginprocedures.php` on all of your sites and you will have a consistent login procedure across them all.

Comment: but could i use a same $_SESSION var between systems? even if they are different apps?

Comment: $_SESSION doesn't know which app is which - it is dependent on domain, however. Including the common file will essentially make them all use a single login method as if they are all part of the same login framework.

Comment: could i use the same session variables from domain.com on admin.domain.com ?? is it considered the same domain? o not?

Comment: This PHP Code will set the session domain to `*.domain.com`, meaning any subdomain. `ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");` - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be best off creating a new login area, with a new database, solely for user management. Let all the apps have access to it's information (Via a single class for example), and use sessions to keep things neat when changing sites.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to all the other sites? My initial thought was to use oAuth but Im not sure if thats what your looking for?

http://oauth.net/

Comment: Using a domain-wide cookie and common database for user auth should be enough for this. No need for OAuth IMO.

Comment: I totally agree when I originally posted he had not told us that everything was running on the same server ;)